# Using onClick to call a JavaScript Function - using form element values...?

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick

I am having some issues with using javascript to get form element values and then using those values to call a function using the 'onClick' attribute.

```
<form name="form1">
<select name="option1">
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
</select>
<input type="image" name="itemid" value="<?=$itemid?>" src="add.png" onclick="window.parent.newAddItem(this.value,form1.elements["option1"].value)" />
</form>
```

I swear this should work? Can anyone advise me if this is something I should be doing, or is there a "best practice" method that is different.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: form1 - sorry, I missed that, it's set above in the onload. I tried to trim the code to something that was just the issue...! doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem probably comes because you're trying to access a 'value' property of the 'select' element instead of the selected option. Try this instead:

```
// On your onclick event handler:
var option1 = form1.elements["option1"];
var selectedOption = option1.options[option1.selectedIndex];
window.parent.newAddItem(this.value, selectedOption.value);
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can get the option's text using `selectedOption.text` btw.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted, oForm is undefined.

Avoid in-line event handlers like you've got there. Instead, bind the event handler centrally. This keeps JS out of your HTML.

Native:

```
var onclick = function() { alert('you clicked me!'); };
var element = document.getElementById('some_element');
document.addEventListener ? element.addEventListener('click', onclick, false) : element.attachEvent('onclick', onclick);
```

jQuery

```
$('#some_element').click(function() { alert('you clicked me!'); });
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your response. My issue is that the input boxes whose data I wish to access is in a jQuery fancybox, which is then closed... so that data would be lost I think? oForm is defined earlier. apologies, I missed that. replace oForm with form1 if it makes it clearer... I'll edit above...